# Error not run code jquery when echo jsoncallback

Tags: jquery, jsonp

In file index.php i using code:

```
<?php
$str = "<script src='click.js'></script>"
$str .= '<div class="box_content_reset"><input type="submit" value="reset" class="reset" /></div>';
echo $_GET["jsoncallback"] . '(' . json_encode($str) . ');';
?>
```

And in file click.js i using code:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $(".reset").click(function() {
                alert("Jquery running ...");
            });
        });
    }
})(); 
</script>
```

=> result not run jquery, how to fix it ?

Comment: check the console log, is there any error in it? what is the rest of the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

you are using :

```
<input type="submit" value="reset" class="reset" />
```

it means your page will refresh automatically when you will click on the button. If you want to use click event then use:

```
<input type="button" value="reset" class="reset" />
```

with your js file

```
<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        jQuery(".reset").click(function() {
            alert("Jquery running ...");
        });
    });
}
})(); 
</script>
```

`jQuery.noConflict();` so that your code will not conflict with `mootools` etc.

Comment: It won't refresh *before the alert appears* (and the alert appearing would clearly show the script running)